# VBA for Inserting a chart into a ppt slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, office-2003

Below is a procedure that I use to pull charts into a ppt from excel spreadsheets. However one thing I cannot figure out is how to insert the picture into the "object" instead of just pasting it onto th screen. (ie if I did a ppLayoutFourObjects, and sent fours charts to this slide, before adding another, I need to know how to paste the chart into each designated rectangle shown from the 4 Objects selection). I know that the first one seems to always be rectangle five, I can't get the code right. Please help.
 This is all 2003 Office.

```
sub xls2ppt()
'I use this to pull charts into ppt from excel   
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWrkBook As Object
Dim lCurrSlide As Long
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
' Open the Excel workbook
Set xlWrkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Budget Overview.xls")
' Copy picture of the 1st chart object onto the clipboard
xlWrkBook.Worksheets(2).ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture
' Get the slide number
lCurrSlide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideNumber
' Paste the picture onto the PowerPoint slide.
ActivePresentation.Slides(lCurrSlide).Shapes.Paste
' Close the open workbook without saving changes
xlWrkBook.Close (False)
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWrkBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help. VBA for PowerPoint is my weakest, but I am really in need to pick it up for work! Thanks guys!

Comment: Are the rectangles placeholders? If so, I believe if you select the placeholder before the paste, the chart will be pasted into the placeholder. (I'm still working on the details of this for my own project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't paste a chart "into an object" in PowerPoint, even through the UI. In Word, you can paste into a textbox or into a table cell, but not in PowerPoint.

What you need to do instead is position the 4 pasted charts so that they're the right size & position - and that's easy enough to do...

```
Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(lCurrSlide)
Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes.Paste
oShape.Top = 10
oShape.Left = 10
oShape.Width = 100
oShape.Height = 100
```